# read s3 text file in powershell script without saving locally

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3, powershell-2.0

`$x = Get-S3Object -BucketName "bucket" -Key "file.txt"`

`Write-Output($x)`

results in

```
 ChecksumAlgorithm : {}
ETag              : "dnjdnjwkfndjfnc"
BucketName        : bucket
Key               : file.txt
LastModified      : 12/29/2022 11:26:20 AM
Owner             : Amazon.S3.Model.Owner
Size              : 37
StorageClass      : STANDARD
```

I want to read the content of this file, not the metadata. I can not use read s3 as it results in saving the file locally. (this script will be run on client so cant touch disk)

Tried below but it results in empty
`$text = $x.Body | Out-String Write-Output($text)`

Comment: Use `Read-S3Object` to read the contents of the object

Comment: @matt.  I can not use read s3 as it results in saving the file locally. (this script will be run on client so cant touch disk)

Comment: The client is the local machine where you can write.  You can't write on a server, but client you can write.  Write to the user temp area (C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Temp).  Other choice is to write to a network drive where you do have access.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party, i know, but you can do this:

$text = (aws s3 cp s3://bucket/file.txt -)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).